# Defining a unique-pairs procedure

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From the section called [Nested Mappings](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html)

> **Exercise 2.40**
>
> Define a procedure
>   unique-pairs that, given an integer `n`,
>   generates the sequence of pairs (`i`,`j`)
>   with `1 < j < i < n`. Use unique-pairs to
>   simplify the definition of
>   prime-sum-pairs given above.

I wrote the following:

```
(define (prime-sum-pairs n)
  (filter (lambda (seq)
            (prime? (+ (car seq) (cadr seq))))
          (unique-pairs n)))

(define (enumerate-integers start end)
  (if (>= start end)
      (list end)
      (cons start (enumerate-integers (+ 1 start) end))))

(define (unique-pairs n)
  (flat-map (lambda (i) 
              (map (lambda (j) (list i j)) 
                   (enumerate-integers 1 (- i 1))))
            (enumerate-integers 2 n)))

(define (filter test-fn seq)
  (if (null? seq) null
      (if (test-fn (car seq)) 
          (cons (car seq)                    
                (filter test-fn (cdr seq)))
          (filter test-fn (cdr seq)))))


(define (accumulate op initial seq)
  (if (null? seq)
      initial
      (op (car seq)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr seq)))))

(define (flat-map f seq)
  (accumulate append
              null
              (map (lambda (x) (f x)) seq)))

(define (prime? n) (= (smallest-divisor n) n))
(define (divisible? n i) (= 0 (remainder n i)))
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (define (rec i)
    (cond ((> n (square i)) n)
          ((divisible? n i) i)
          (else (rec (+ 1 i)))))
  (rec 2))
```

Can this be improved in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
(define (enumerate-integers start end)
  (if (>= start end)
      (list end)
      (cons start (enumerate-integers (+ 1 start) end))))

(define (unique-pairs n)
  (flat-map (lambda (i) 
              (map (lambda (j) (list i j)) 
                   (enumerate-integers 1 (- i 1))))
            (enumerate-integers 2 n)))
```

looks fine to me. If you want to massage some details, you could rewrite enumerate-integers e.g. to:

```
(define (enumerate-integers start end)
  (if (> start end) '()
      (cons start (enumerate-integers (+ 1 start) end))))
```

which is cleaner because you don't have (list end) as a special case, and you can correctly produce an empty list of integers if start > end.

If you want to be even cleaner, you can do:

```
(define (enumerate-integers start end)
  (define (iter n)
    (if (> n end) '()
        (cons n (iter (+ n 1)))))
  (iter start))
```

This is a good pattern in case of more complex procedures.

Your flat-map is more complex than needed, your code:

```
(define (flat-map f seq)
  (accumulate append
              null
              (map (lambda (x) (f x)) seq)))
```

can be replaced with:

```
(define (flat-map f seq)
  (accumulate append
              null
              (map f seq)))
```

because (lambda (x) (f x)) is equal to f.